# Buffered pipeline using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm currently scrapping a website using [Scrapy 0.24](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html). The website has the following url format:

```
www.site.com?category={0}&item={1}&page={2}
```

I have a `MySQLStorePipeline` which is responsible for storing each scrapped item in the database. But I have 80 categories, 10 items and 15 pages, which results in `80 * 10 * 15 = 120000` pages.  Each page I yield 25 `scrapy.Item`s, which give us `25 * 120000 = 3000000` rows in the database.

So, every time the pipeline receives an item, it inserts into the database. And it is not a smart way. I'm looking for a way to buffer the pipeline items and, for example, when we receive 1000 items, execute a bulk insert. How can I achieve that?

Comment: have you already analyzed the scenario using the spider close signal ?

Comment: @aberna Not yet. What would you suggest?

Comment: @aberna According to the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#spider-closed), I don't have access to the scrapped item in this signal. Just the spider itself and the reason the spider has been closed.

Comment: Here on SO some proposed an approach. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768247/how-to-access-all-scraped-items-in-scrapy-item-pipeline You can keep track of your item and process them all together when you intercept the spider signal

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have the pipeline store items in a list, and insert them when they reach a certain length, and on spider closing.

```
class Pipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Pipeline, self).__init__()
        self.items = []

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.items.append(item)
        if len(self.items) >= 1000:
            self.insert_current_items()
        return item

    def insert_current_items(self):
        items = self.items
        self.items = []
        self.insert_to_database(items)

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.insert_current_items()
```

Comment: I feel ashamed now. How couldn't I think about it?

Comment: @Doon I feel the same :D I guess we were looking for some kind of built-in "supported" (thus better, cough cough) way.

Comment: Great solution. Only issue -- what happens when you get to fewer than 1000 items in a batch? The rest of the records wont get inserted.

Comment: @BenWilson that's why it also inserts on `close_spider` event.