# How to get scraped items from main script using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I hope to get a list of scraped items in main script instead of using scrapy shell.

I know there is a method `parse` in class `FooSpider` I define, and this method return a list of `Item`. Scrapy framework calls this method. But, how can I get this returned list by myself?

I found so many posts about that, but I don't understand what they were saying.

As a context, I put official example code here

```
import scrapy

from tutorial.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css("ul.directory.dir-col > li > a::attr('href')"):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        result = []
        for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
            item = DmozItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['desc'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            result.append(item)

        return result
```

How could I get returned `result` from a main python script like `main.py` or `run.py`?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    result = xxxx()
    for item in result:
        print item
```

Could anyone provide a code snippet in which I get this returned `list` from somewhere?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you add more context into where do you want to access this list of items and for what reason? Thanks!

Comment: You can run your spider with `scrapy run dmoz -o items.json` to scrape all the items and save them in a file called `items.json` in a json format and later, load with another script with something like `json.loads(data)`

Comment: @GustavoCarvalho It will slow down crawler and has file lock and synchronous issues.  Could I do all of work in scripts?

Comment: Yes, it does have these problems. This is approach is not supposed to be run at the same time as the crawler.
You can run the spider through a script like this[1], but it seems that you can't access the items the way you want.

[1] http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script

Comment: To anyone looking to just do something with the items after they've all been collected (e.g. look at them in the debugger), this is answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768247/how-to-access-all-scraped-items-in-scrapy-item-pipeline

Comment: You can also refer to my stackoverflow answer o tis here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70876325/10468153

Answer (score 8):

This is an example how you can collect all items in a list with a Pipeline:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# Scrapy API imports
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

# your spider
from FollowAllSpider import FollowAllSpider

# list to collect all items
items = []

# pipeline to fill the items list
class ItemCollectorPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        items.append(item)

# create a crawler process with the specified settings
process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'scrapy',
    'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': { '__main__.ItemCollectorPipeline': 100 }
})

# start the spider
process.crawl(FollowAllSpider)
process.start()

# print the items
for item in items:
    print("url: " + item['url'])
```

You can get `FollowAllSpider` from [here](https://github.com/scrapinghub/testspiders/blob/master/testspiders/spiders/followall.py), or use your own spider. Example output when using it with my webpage:

```
$ ./crawler.py 
2018-09-16 22:28:09 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2018-09-16 22:28:09 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 3.7.1.0, libxml2 2.9.4, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.7.0, Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) - [GCC 6.3.0 20170118], pyOpenSSL 16.2.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017), cryptography 1.7.1, Platform Linux-4.9.0-6-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-9.5
2018-09-16 22:28:09 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'USER_AGENT': 'scrapy', 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO'}
[...]
2018-09-16 22:28:15 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
url: http://www.frank-buss.de/
url: http://www.frank-buss.de/impressum.html
url: http://www.frank-buss.de/spline.html
url: http://www.frank-buss.de/schnecke/index.html
url: http://www.frank-buss.de/solitaire/index.html
url: http://www.frank-buss.de/forth/index.html
url: http://www.frank-buss.de/pi.tex
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to work with/process/transform or store the items you should look into the [Item Pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) and the usual scrapy crawl would do the trick.